# React-native application fetch http so slow

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux, react-native-flatlist, react-native-image

I just first time to develop an react-native application. I'm using `react-native-router-flux` for navigation and have to create an feed page that showing feed in `Image` and `Text` component using react-native `FlatList`. The problem is, the application is so slow at getting some data from from remote server, even using localhost.

the data is formated like this

```
{
    [
        title : "Test title",
        description : "Test Description",
        imageUrl : 'http://192.168.22.22:8887/image.png'
    ],
    [
        title : "Test title 2",
        description : "Test Description 2",
        imageUrl : 'http://192.168.22.22:8887/image2.png'
    ]
}
```

I have tried to accessing the api url from browser and it done fast as well. But when I'm accessing via my react-native application, it so slow. Like 7 second to wait the page done to load the fetch data. I think the problem is when im using image from remote data. I'm do it like this

```
<Image
    style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
    source={{uri: HOST_URL + '/' + rowData.imageUrl }}
/>
```

Is this posible to improve the speed? Is using the loading remote `Image` influence the speed? Or I must loading images using lazy image loading concept?

Comment: Are you remote debugging while fetching data? In some situations, turning "remote debugging" off helps greatly.

Comment: Stupid question but worth mentioning: Are you running in a simulator and have you set a network speed limit?

Comment: Basically, I'm using wifi debugging on my phone without "remote debugging" btw

Answer (score 0):

if you dont have too much images you can save them in your project and use `requie("// the address of image in your project")` in the source